# Override html template file in Magento 2 not working

Tags: magento2, template, frontend, requirejs, billing-address

I want to override **Magento 2 html template** located at

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/billing-address/details.html

I tried using `require-config.js` for `frontend` like this:

```
var config = { 
    map: {
       '*': {
         'Magento_Checkout/template/billing-address/details':
             'Namespace_Module/template/billing-address/details'
    }
  }
};
```

and I put that file at

> Namespace/Module/view/frontend/template/billing-address/details.html

But I got the following error:

```
Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/Vendor/vendor_theme/en_US/Namespace_Module/template/billing-address/details.html' #0 /var/www/rotoki/vendor/magento/framework/App/StaticResource.php(97)
```

I think **Magento** is trying to find that file inside my theme folder instead of my module folder.

Comment: please let me know if i have use custom module then how override?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just copy file from

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/billing-address/details.html
```

And put it to

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/YourTheme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/billing-address/details.html
```

Run below commads for deploy static content

> ```
> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
> php bin/magento cache:clean
> ```

Comment: Thanks, I had seen advice elsewhere that leaves out the '/web/' part of the path in the custom theme. Putting 'template' folder in 'web' made the override work 

Answer (score 3):

**You should give first priority to custom module for override html template files and give second priority to custom theme**

To override html file with a custom theme you need not **require-config.js**.

As you question you use custom module to override html files that's good.

Check your path you need to copy in **`details.html`** at

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/billing-address/details.html

After flush cache and refresh page, `details.html` is created or copied in **pub/static** folder at

> pub/static/frontend/cendor/theme/en_US(Language)/Magento_Checkout/template/billing-address/details.html

Answer (score 2):

You were so close yourself to the best answer:

```
var config = { 
    map: {
       '*': {
         'Magento_Checkout/template/billing-address/details.html':
             'Namespace_Module/template/billing-address/details.html'
    }
  }
};
```

Please accept this answer, because rewriting template in design catalog might not be the best solution, especially if you trying to add new functionality via your own module (which is recommended way of tweaking Magento to your needs).